# Like + Dislikes Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, comments

I am working on a web programing assignment for University and have hit a snag when trying to make a like and dislike function for a comments area of a guestbook.

Evectively the numbers on the site should update by one once either the dislike or like button is pressed.

My comments display correctly however the liking function is broken and I have no idea how to fix it.

Here is my code

```
Controller (LikesController.php)

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LikesController extends Controller (It says my Like Controller is never used not sure why this is)
{
    public function likepl (Comment, $comment) { (Says that Comment is "Undefined" also not sure why this is)
        $comment -> likePlus (); (Method likePlus not found)
        return redirect () -> action ('CommentController@index');
    }
}




Model (comment.php)

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{

    public static function paginate(int $COMMENTS_PER_PAGE)
    {
    }


    public function likePlus()
    {
        $this -> likes += 1;
        $this -> update ();
    }

    public function dislikePlus()
    {
        $this -> dislikes += 1;
        $this -> update ();
    }
}




View Page (comment.comments)

@extends('setup')
@section('content')
    <div class="container main-table">
        <div class="box">
            <h1 class="title">Guest book Comments</h1>
            @if (count ($comments) > 5)
                <table class="table is-striped is-hoverable">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>User</th>
                        <th>Comment</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Likes</th>
                        <th>DisLikes</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr>
                    @foreach ($comments as $c)
{{--declaring the comments--}}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $c -> user }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $c -> comments }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $c -> created_at -> format ('D jS F') }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $c -> likes }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $c -> dislikes }}</td>
                        </tr>

                    <tr class="icon heart">
                        <td><a class="button" href="/comment/{{ $c -> id }}/like/"><ion-icon name="md-heart"></ion-icon></a></td>
                        <td><a class="button" href="/comment/{{ $c -> id }}/dislike/"><ion-icon name="md-heart-empty"></ion-icon></a></td>
                    </tr>
                        @endforeach
                </table>
                {{ $comments -> links() }} {{-- Setting pagination--}}
                        @else
                <div class="notification is-info">
                    <p>
                        The Guest book is empty. Why not add a comment?
                    </p>
                </div>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

I have annotated the code with the visible errors that I get as for better refference.

Here are the Routes that I am using for the comments page.

```
Route::get('/','CommentController@index');
Route::get('/comment/{comment}/like/', 'LikesController@likePl');
Route::get('/comment/{comment}/dislike/', 'DislikesController@dislikePl');
```

Answer (score 2):

The `update()` function does not work the way you are using it. You either update the property and use the `save()` function, or you pass an array to the update function.

```
// 1.
$this->likes += 1;
$this->save();

// 2.
$this->update([
    'likes' => $this->likes + 1,
]);
```

---

**Update:** Even better would be to use the built-in [`increment()`](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_increment) function:

```
$this->increment('likes');
```

This way there is no need to know the number of likes beforehand.

Comment: Glad I could help, consider marking this as the answer so other users might find this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can we please work on the following first.

1. LikePl function name should match the name on the router (action@method)
2. The method inside the controller accept [request](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests) like so

   **public function likePl (Request $request) { //code here }**
3. Methods inside the Model are accessed using their namespace like so
   **App\Comment::likePlus()** or you can import the namespace like "use App\Comment" there after inside the method just simply do "**Comment::likePlus()**".
4. Please refer here [Laravel models](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#retrieving-models) for more information.

   Fixing this will remove the errors you currently have. Use "**dd($request->all())**" inside your likePl method to check if you are getting the values you expect.

Hope this help a bit...